# Как получить идентификатор элемента страницы в расширении Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Ниже приведен код работы контекстного меню расширения.
Например я кликаю в текстовый input. Как мне получить его идентификатор, чтобы вывести строку не в alert, а вставить в input?

Все пальцы обгуглил - не нашел решения...

```js
// background.js
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
        endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
        el.value = val.slice(0, el.selectionStart) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.selection.createRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.text = text;
        range.select();
    }
}

function pasteRandom(info, tab) {
 if(info.menuItemId == "c_name"){
  chrome.storage.sync.get("name", function (obj){
   alert(obj.name);
  });
 }
 else if(info.menuItemId == "c_email"){
  chrome.storage.sync.get("email", function (obj){
   alert(obj.email);
  });
 }

 /*alert("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
 alert("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
 alert("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));*/
}

 
var root = chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "Вставить данные из RandomUser" ,
    id: "c_root", 
 contexts:["editable"]
});

var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "Имя", 
 parentId: root,
 id:"c_name", 
 contexts:["editable"]
});

var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "Email", 
 parentId: root,
 id:"c_email", 
 contexts:["editable"]
});


//alert("parent:" + root + " child1:" + child1 + " child2:" + child2);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(pasteRandom);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придётся ставить слушатель на событие `click` (правой кнопкой) в `content-script`. При наступлении события передавать информацию об элементе в `background`.

Также ставим слушатель в `background` на клик в `context-menu`. При наступлении события у нас уже есть в `background` информация о необходимом элементе.

Нечто похожее можно увидеть здесь: [content-script](https://github.com/Fenex/KTS/blob/d7113e2d139c90426a92eda56ed2c6c4b0e9b1f9/beforeContextMenu.js#L15), [background](https://github.com/Fenex/KTS/blob/master/ex_listener.js#L164). Там создаются необходимые пункты меню при каждом нажатии правой кнопкой мышки на страницах, и соответственно обрабатываются по-разному.